# NuGet Package Manager error when saving package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-explorer

I'm using NuGet Package Explorer to create nugget packages, but when I want to save a package in any folder in my PC it throw me a error that says: `The file exists` and in the folder there is no other nuget package.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like a temporal file problem,you can try cleaning the windows cache, using for example CCleaner